# braces in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have a brace in a tikz picture. However, when I process the file

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
  \def\C{(0.688191,0)}
  \def\D{(0.688191, 0.1844)}
  \def\E{(0.830424, 0.1844)}
  \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] \C -- \D;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent
name ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                    

l.10 \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]  
                                      \C -- \D;

help. Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I saw similar questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154334/package-pgfkeys-error-i-do-not-know-the-key-tikz-name-intersection) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217700/tikz-crosses-decoration-does-not-work) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159508/braces-in-tikz-picture), but the answers to them don't seem to help me. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please don't quote code. Use the `{}` button or ctrl+k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `decorations.pathreplacing` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
  \def\C{(0.688191,0)} \def\D{(0.688191, 0.1844)} \def\E{(0.830424, 0.1844)}
  \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] \C -- \D;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: brace]